# Powershell + wpf xaml + Tabs - change tab

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, tabs

After reading [FoxDeploy's tutorial](https://foxdeploy.com/2015/09/08/powershell-guis-how-to-handle-events-and-create-a-tabbed-interface/) on building a PowerShell GUI with WPF and XAML, I built my own app with tabs. However, I am struggling to get my Tabs to behave the way I want.

XAML file

```
<Window x:Class="Tabs.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tabs"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid Width="500">
    <TabControl x:Name="TabControl">
        <TabItem x:Name="Tab1" Header="First" Width="70">
            <Grid x:Name="Tab1Grid" Background="#FFD4D4D4">
                <Label Content="Tab 1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="18" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF5D5656" Foreground="White"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnTab2" Content="Go to tab 2 " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="405,256,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="Tab2" Header="Second" Width="70">
            <Grid x:Name="Tab2Grid" Background="#FFD4D4D4">
                <Label Content="This is the second tab" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="18" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FF5D5656" Foreground="White"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

PS1 file

```
$inputXML = Get-Content -Path path_to_MainTabbedWindow.xaml
$inputXML = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N'  -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[xml]$XAML = $inputXML
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
try { $Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader ) }
catch { Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Double-check syntax and ensure .net is installed." }
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name "WPF$($_.Name)" -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}

$WPFbtnTab2.Add_Click({
    # change focus to Tab 2
    # populate a listview based on input on tab 1
})

$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

[Picture of PS GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSKjR.png)

So, when I click "Go to tab 2" I want to show the tab - same as clicking above - but I also want to populate a list view on Tab 2 based on some content entered on Tab 1.

Is it possible with Tabs in the same way I have written above or do I need to use different Form objects for the tabs and hide/show as required (same thing, right)?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help.

Comment: Why don't you try? 

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, looks like a good break away from the kbd and a comment from Mathias clicked the right brain cells in place.

This did the trick:

```
$WPFTabControl.Items[0].IsSelected = $false
$WPFTabControl.Items[1].IsSelected = $true
```